# Highcharts legend unfold and expand

Tags: highcharts

Um looking for a way to maximize and minimize a highcharts menu. I could not find a way to do that in their API . Can anyone know a  way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling I found answers , hope these will be useful

```
[a link](http://jsfiddle.net/P2g6H/)

 [a link](http://jsfiddle.net/hrrL4max/1/)
```